# Is there any way for a consumer to confirm that a device is actually UL listed?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance

In the current day and age it's possible to buy any number of interesting and hard to find electrical devices on Amazon and Alibaba from resellers of unknown reputation. Anyone can stamp a UL label on their device, and the consumer is none the wiser. Obviously its safest to buy from a reputable domestic electrical supply distributor or big box store, but sometimes you are looking for something they don't carry. That got me thinking - is there anywhere for a consumer to find these UL lists or any way to otherwise confirm that an item is actually UL listed?

(If this isn't the right place to ask this question, I welcome being pointed to the right place.)

Comment: Not sure if I should post this as a comment or an answer. The thing with places like Amazon is that you *can not* guarantee you are getting a genuine product - and therefore you also can't guarantee that what you're getting is actually UL listed.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, UL has an online database that you can search: https://productiq.ulprospector.com/en/search

It helps to have the product’s UL file number (which should be on the product near the UL logo and/or in the manual, or pre-purchase ask the vendor) and you can also search by manufacturer.

Comment: That search tool does not provide what this question requests.  Read it's own  [About](https://iq2.ulprospector.com/en/about), and try searching for your toaster... you can't because it's not for that.

Comment: There is a paid access to that site, maybe that delivers ... I don't know.  And there is a phone number on that page where allegedly you can validate listings.

Comment: The free access seem to work fine for me. If I search for model “PD-6ANS” (the model of a Lutron smart switch I have) or for manufacturer “Emporia” (maker of my EVSE), it shows that file numbers exist for both.

Comment: @jay613 -- the about page isn't even close to a complete description of what all is available through the UL Product iQ database

Answer (score 4):

You can search UL's database (likely ETL and others have similar databases) to determine if the listing *appears* to be real (of course if it's counterfeit they can just copy the listing number of an existing product so it's not 100% sure).

If the product does not have the four required elements on it then it's probably not really listed:

[image]

If your 'devices' includes components, with the backwards UR symbol, the requirements are similar.

Comment: I imagine those could be quite easily faked.

Comment: @SteveWellens Yes, the idea is that if it *lacks* those elements it's probably not listed. The presence of them is necessary but insufficient.

Comment: Point taken.  FYI:  I got a device UL approved.  The UL rep required the calibration history of the measuring instruments!

Comment: @SteveWellens was that a one-time thing at approval or an ongoing inspection? Just curious.

Comment: It was for a component (transformer) used in other products.  We better stop having this conversation or we'll get yelled at!  (Weird: I use the at sign to put your name in the post and it disappears).